# Show/Hide of QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmenu

I created the Start Menu by inheriting `QMenu`. I want to show and hide it using `QPropertyAnimation` in sliding style

**Problem:**
Show & hide are working fine when I call them explicitly(on click of start button). But when I click outside of start menu it hides instantly. Please suggest me what could be cause behind this:

```
My class is StartMenuUiClass which inherited from QMenu
mptrobj_animation is QPropertyAnimation object

void StartMenuUiClass::show()
{
    this->raise();
    disconnect(mptrobj_animation,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(this_hide()));
    QMenu::show();
    mptrobj_animation->setDuration(500);
    mptrobj_animation->setStartValue(*mptrobj_startPosition);
    mptrobj_animation->setEndValue(*mptrobj_endPosition);
    mptrobj_animation->start();
}

void StartMenuUiClass::hide()
{
    mptrobj_animation->setDuration(450);
    mptrobj_animation->setStartValue(*mptrobj_endPosition);
    mptrobj_animation->setEndValue(*mptrobj_startPosition);
    connect(mptrobj_animation,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(this_hide()));
    mptrobj_animation->start();
}

void StartMenuUiClass::this_hide()
{
    this->lower();
    emit work_Done();
    QMenu::hide();
}
```

Comment: it may be related to QMenu signal aboutToHide(), you can connect a slot to it which can perform a check hide or not like so.

Comment: I would suggest to install connection **before** calling `start()` function in your `StartMenuUiClass::hide()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you click outside of your menu widget, it simply hides or closes without involving your `StartMenuUiClass::hide()` function. You can try to handle `QMenu::hideEvent(QHideEvent *event)` and/or `QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)`. Something like this:

```
StartMenuUiClass::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) // the same for hideEvent()
{
    this->hide();
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: @Jai, what did you do and what is happening?

Comment: I override hideEvent and closeEvent as you said before. But same thing is happening, when i click my start button start menu is showing and hiding properly but when i click outside menu it hide instantly